# Virtual MIDI Keyboard - get the output

Tags: keyboard, midi

I'm a beginner in using MIDI, and I try to use my Virtual MIDI keyboard (http://vmpk.sourceforge.net/) and to monitor all incoming MIDI-events in MIDI-OX, but it doesn't work. (I use Windows 7)

But I'm a bit confused about the inputs and outputs:
So I select "Windows MM" as Midi-Out driver in vmpk ("Windows MM" and "FluidSynth" and "Network" are available) and "2-MIDI OUT" as connection of the MIDI output ("Microsoft Midi Mapper" and "Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth" are available).

So, in MIDI-OX I select "2-MIDI IN" as MIDI-Input (it's the only one which is available), but the output of the keyboard is not monitored in MIDI-OX Input Monitor.

Which inputs / outputs do I have to use when I want to monitor this? Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this. http://vmpk.sourceforge.net/#MIDI_Connections
I think you will find your answers. The solution is to install a "virtual midi cable".